# Why does Doctrine PostPersist Event miss the first Instance element of my fixture class?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm developing a web app using the symfony4 framework. In this app I deal with events. Those events are linked to users via another class called Participation. To make sure that a newcomer cannot register for past Event, I create the participations at the first persistance of the event adding a participation for all the already registered Users. To do so I declared a service

```
service: 
    App\EventListener\CreateParticipations:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

Defined as such:

```php
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use App\Entity\Participation;
use App\Entity\Event;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CreateParticipations
{
    private $em; // EntityManager

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

        $event = $args->getObject();

        if ($event instanceof Event) { 

            $users = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();
            $nbUser = count($users);
            for ($i=0; $i < $nbUser; $i++)
            {
                $participation = new Participation ();
                $participation->setUser($users[$i]);
                $participation->setEvent($event);

                $this->em->persist($participation);
            }

            $this->em->flush();
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine with the add/new event procedure that I've created. But when I create some fixture to test my app with this code :

```php
class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        //creation of the users and tags
        //event creator
        $nbEvent = 1;
        $events = array($nbEvent);
        for ($i=0; $i< $nbEvent; $i++)
        {
            $events[$i] = new Event();

            $date = $faker->dateTimeThisMonth($max = 'now', $timezone = null);
            $fin = new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $events[$i]->setStart($date);
            $events[$i]->setFinish($fin->add(new \DateInterval('PT2H')));
            $events[$i]->setInfo($faker->sentence(10, true));
            $events[$i]->setMaxPlayers(10);
            $events[$i]->setName($faker->word());
            $events[$i]->setTag($tag[$faker->numberBetween(0, 2)]);
            $events[$i]->setActive(true);

            $location = new Location();
            $location->setFullAdr($faker->address());
            $location->setLat($faker->latitude($min = -90, $max = 90));
            $location->setLng($faker->longitude($min = -180, $max = 180));

            $events[$i]->setLocation($location);

            $manager->persist($events[$i]);

        }
    }
}
```

the first event flushed in my database has no Participation associated. Do you see where this strange behavior comes from ?

As it is my first post on stack overflow, do not hesitate to correct me if my question is unclear

Comment: In your code there's the comment `creation of the users and tags`. Are there any users in the database at this point?

Comment: nope at this point there are no users

Comment: Well maybe there's your issue. You are creating Participations in the loop `for ($i=0; $i < $nbUser; $i++)`. So if there're no users un the DB, the code in the loop will not be executed.

Comment: ok so All my users were persisted but that was not sufficient. I added a `$manager->flush()` of all my users before creating the events and it works like a charm. still don't understand why it was at first partially working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [Zak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2661253/zak) explained, the problem comes from the persistence of my `Users` before adding new participations.

All the `Users` need to be flushed in the DB before creating new events.

Thanks for your help!